# How do you clear sprites in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

Pygame has the method `clear` for the `Group` class which is used to group sprites together. When I call clear on my `Group` object I can successfully clear the images of all my sprites in that group, but the hitboxes of my sprites remain. I was wondering if there is another way to remove both my sprite's image AND the rectangle hitbox without destroying the sprite object.

Comment: maybe you have the same sprites in other group which you use to check collisions. You may have to remove sprites from all groups.

Comment: you can keep objects in other group or list - so they will be not removed from memory (will be not destroyed). But don't use this group to draw and/or check collisions.

Comment: I only have one Group object. I want to remove the graphics and the hitbox from the view but keep the data in the model.

Comment: what model ? And hitbox should be inside the same class Sprite with graphics - so if you remove sprite then you remove both - graphics and hitbox.

Comment: maybe you created somethind different then standard Sprite ? Maybe you should create minimal working code with your problem so we could run it and see problem.

Comment: I'm trying to use MVC design pattern. I agree that if you remove the sprite it should remove both the graphics and hitbox, but how do I do this in pygame?

Comment: I never saw MVC in game - only in web frameworks

Comment: oh, well the data is separate from the graphics. So when I say Model I mean the data and when I say View I mean the graphics. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: you will have to create minimal working code to show problem - without example there is no answer for your problem

Comment: Sure thing: https://github.com/SebastianRuan/PygameTest/blob/master/pygame_tests.py

Comment: [clear](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.clear) is used only to clear current screen so you could draw sprites in new place - it could make code faster  because you don't have to redraw all screen again. it is not used to remove sprites from group. To remove you should rather use `my_block.kill()`

Comment: BTW: if you add `my_group.draw(screen)` inside `while`-loop then it will draw it all time.

Comment: BTW: but I see other problem - you check mouse position directly with `my_block` not with `group` - so even if you remove it from group you still will compare mouse position directly with `my_block`, not with empty group.

Answer (score 1):

You should check mouse position with elements in group and `kill()` element to remove from group. After that you can use `clean()` to remove all elements from screen and `draw()` again to redraw only elements which are still in group

```
        x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        for item in my_group:
            if item.rect.collidepoint(x, y):
                print("Collision detected")
                item.kill()
                my_group.clear(screen, background)
                my_group.draw(screen)
```

---

I created two elements in group so you will see difference if you remove `draw()` after `clear()` - it will remove all elements from screen

```
import pygame

# --- constants ---

# Define some colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

SIZE = (700, 500)

# --- classes ---

class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # Constructor. Pass in the color of the block,
    # and its x and y position
    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()

        # Create an image of the block, and fill it with a color.
        # This could also be an image loaded from the disk.
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Obrazy/images/square-1.png").convert()

        # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image
        # Update the position of this object by setting the values of rect.x and rect.y
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

# --- functions ---

# empty

# --- main ---

pygame.init()

# Set the height and width of the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)

pygame.display.set_caption("Testing Screen")

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

my_block1 = Block(WHITE, 20, 20)
my_block2 = Block(WHITE, 20, 20)
my_block2.rect.x = 100

my_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
my_group.add(my_block1)
my_group.add(my_block2)

background = pygame.Surface(SIZE)

screen.fill(BLACK)
#screen.blit(background, (0,0))
my_group.draw(screen)

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------

while not done:
    # Set the screen background
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

            for item in my_group:
                if item.rect.collidepoint(x, y):
                    print("Collision detected")
                    item.kill()
                    my_group.clear(screen, background)
                    my_group.draw(screen)

    # Limit to 60 frames per second
    clock.tick(60)

    #my_group.clear(screen, background)
    #my_group.draw(screen)

    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

# Be IDLE friendly. If you forget this line, the program will 'hang'
# on exit.
pygame.quit()
```

---

BTW: in Python 3 you can use

```
super().__init__()
```

instead of

```
pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
```